# Design best practices for Form

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

Are there any best practices, example forms or do/don't lists or tips when it comes to designing paper forms for the Form Recognizer API? I'm in the lucky position that I can make changes to forms to make them more suitable for the API.

I designed the form in Word. It's got letterhead and heading as a header, a text area for customer information, date, and work description and a table with three columns: Item/product, unit, amount. The form is filled in by hand by mobile repair/install workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best practice, only the offical tutorial [`Build a training data set for a custom model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/build-training-data-set).

May you just think to design some form samples to feed the Form Recognizer model for improving the performance and accuracy, but as I said in my answer of the SO thread [How to improve the accuracy of Form Recognizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662250/how-to-improve-the-accuracy-of-form-recognizer/57670842#57670842), you just need to follow the offical tutorial and feed the training model with more real form images to adapt the different form design.