# If I want 5 values that are in columns to the right of each key, what is the ideal way to train the Form Recognizer?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, training-data, azure-form-recognizer

I have a column of numbers [to the far left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS0xy.png) as my keys, of which, each entry has 5 design values I'm trying to pair to it. To train the model, I've used 15 completed pdf files, most of which were not scans. I also edited 3 of those, deleting the values but leaving the keys, and saved them with the same file name as the original, suffixed with "Empty".
The results returned from the model have no problem finding any of the numbers or their locations, but they are not in key-value pairs of any kind. I get that key-value "pair" excludes any possibility of grabbing the column header and the row, but just the row and position relative to the others would be make things easy enough. Just hoping for some insight on how to train it to reuse the same key as it looks across the row.

I'm exporting the data to Word format and tabulating the values [with a light border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnZUe.png). I have no experience with machine learning. For the empty form, would there be any benefit to adding DocVariable fields to each of the 5 value columns, with the variable name being a combination of the row and column key names?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's necessary to delete these keys from your sample data to train the model of Form Recognizer, even incorrect to do that. Form Recognizer need to learn what key is in your sample data.

So you just need to follow the offical tutorial [`Build a training data set for a custom model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/build-training-data-set) to train the model with more samples of the similar form layout with different keys and different value. Then, you can follow my answer for the SO thread [How to improve the accuracy of Form Recognizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662250/how-to-improve-the-accuracy-of-form-recognizer/57670842#57670842) to draw the keys and values and extract the values what you want from the json result by their `boundingBox` values.

Yes, what I said means you need to design an algorithm to classify these keys and values by classifing their geometry values of `boundingBox`.

For example, you can try to draw several horizontal or vertical lines to link these left-up point of keys and values and to find out the geometry point pattern for classification these form cells.

Comment: That was the conclusion I came to, although I didn't realize I was supposed to remove the keys as well as the values. I also tried shading every other row and using different colors for each columns without much luck. I'm using as much data as it will allow me to upload, on the trial at least. I also tried to use the [API](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api/operations/TrainCustomModel/console) to force feed it the keys. If there are any examples for the proper use of it, I couldn't find them. It looks like the most promising.